# Python process blocking main thread

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I can't figure out why a Python process would block the main thread. An example:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def do_something(name: str):
    while True:
        print(name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something, args=(1,))
    p1.start()

    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something, args=(2,))
    p2.start()

    while True:
        print(3)
        time.sleep(.1)
```

The output result of this is a whole bunch of 1 and 2's. While 3 (main process/thread) is never printed. When I remove the time.sleep it starts printing again. Why is it that a time.sleep can make Processes block the main thread?

Comment: On a side note, you've annotated `do_something` as taking a `str` argument yet you're passing in `int`s.

Comment: My guess is the 3s, which are spaced out by `time.sleep`, are being printed yet they're drowned out by the 1s and 2s which have no such spacing.  Try putting `time.sleep(1)` in `do_something` and see if that changes things.

Comment: You are totally right. The type hinting is an oversight on my part but shouldn't impact anything important here. It does get drowned out. However, in another project I have with a lot more code it's actually behaving like I was suggesting. It's an application using OpenGL and the main loop slows down to a point it's not even running anymore whenever I have a while loop inside a process.

Answer (score 1):

If you pipe the output to a text file, you'll find that it does indeed print 3. However, it only prints roughly every 100 ms whereas the other two processes print continuously so you might not see it in the console.